# Is there a way to join arrays, but with numbering?

Tags: javascript

So, I tried to join an array, but everytime it joined an item, it would add a number too. I can't figure out how should I do this.
`message.channel.send(lennies.join("\n"+(num+1)))` - this is my current code.

Comment: doesnt really work ^

Comment: your question is not really clear too  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ah ok i'll check that out and ask my question in a better fashion

Comment: To help you, we need to better understand the issue. When you updated your question its good to include: What are you trying to do? What are the steps you've taken, what do you expect to happen and what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

If I read you correctly, you want to join an array of strings, and also insert a number first.

Maybe something like this?:

```js
const lennies = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

lennies
  .map((value, index) => `(${index}) ${value}`)
  .join('\n');

// "(0) a
// (1) b
// (2) c"
```

Comment: ah it works, thanks! I'll try learning more  js so i dont have to rely on ppl

Comment: No problem @neko

But if you agree with the answer, you should click to accept it. And maybe press the arrow up button to show your appreciation :)